# Can't import bootstrap in wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem with adding boostrap to wordpress child theme.

This is how it looks my folder in child theme:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eNCE.jpg

and there is content from css folder
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iO7lF.jpg

In function.php I tried this:

```
function theme_add_bootstrap() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '3.0.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_add_bootstrap' );
```

But not working, in index.php I wrote class `col-sm-3`  and in inspect element of Chrome not reading class and styles from bootstrap.

Can you help me, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

To load the child theme's assets, use the **get_stylesheet_directory_uri** function instead of **get_template_directory_uri** function.

```
function theme_add_bootstrap() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'style-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '3.0.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_add_bootstrap' );
```

You can also check WordPress [Child Theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) for more information.

Comment: You can verify if the files are successfully loaded by opening the browser developer tools, then navigate to the network tab, specifically filter the assets you'd like to check. In that way, you can verify if assets are successfully loaded.

Comment: It the attached image, the filter is for images, hence the selected filter is for IMG, try clicking the CSS, JS filter, and refresh the page.

Comment: sorry wrong attached image, I tried also for js and css same result :(

Comment: Please read the documentation for WordPress [Child Themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) it is a thorough document so there's a 100% chance that reading the guide will solve your problem.

Great developers will always starts by reading the official documentation for their specific tool-set.

Comment: hmm i've created child theme already. copied neccesary instyle.css and call URI etc...